# Converting Nested For Loop with Rolling Function to apply

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, xts

Currently, have an XTS variable with several columns and my goal is to apply a certain rolling function to each column of the dataset. The nested for loop approach that I am using below is very slow and I understand that apply statements may help speed up the process. I was wondering if anyone could guide me on the best way to convert the nested for loops to apply statements or just ways in which to speed up the code in general.

Head of part of the data set:

```
Data <-
structure(c(-0.003703704, 0.038104089, -0.000895255, -0.002389486, 
0.00988024, 0.00889416, 0.002514368, 0.020781082, 0.002457002, 
-0.023459384, 0.019361778, 0.004220893, -0.048253968, 0.105737158, 
0.04147813, -0.03070239, 0.039593605, 0.033774073, -0.002636625, 
0.020908435, -0.003766478, -0.002126654, 0.004972768, 0.005655042, 
-0.003175947, 0.013169074, -0.01572327, 0.003833866, 0.00466794, 
-0.004223865, 0.010963195, -0.004802479, -0.005292653, -0.003286385, 
0.011775789, 0.000310366, 0.002399232, 0.038774533, -0.014746544, 
-0.004209542, 0.039924847, -0.004968383, 0.029471545, -0.000987167, 
-0.005928854, -0.005964215, 0.007, -0.002979146, 0.005352645, 
0.002818666, 0, -0.00843223, 0.004724409, -0.005642633, -0.013913043, 
0.005291005, 0.026315789, 0.015384615, -0.03030303, 0.029513889, 
0.076259947, -0.017868145, -0.010037641, 0.002534854, -0.003792668, 
-0.021573604, 0.037435657, 0.00947226, -0.023235031, 0.005032022, 
-0.017296313, -0.004168597, 0.020424195, 0.056197075, 0.021137026, 
-0.017130621, -0.007262164, 0.00658376, -0.014313598, -0.027062706, 
0.05156038, 0.059354839, -0.018879415, 0.037243948, 0, 0.009724257, 
-0.00171504, -0.021540901, 0.014721772, -0.012777852), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC",
index = structure(c(1073001600, 1073260800, 1073347200, 1073433600, 1073520000,
1073606400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L, 15L),
.Dimnames = list(NULL, c("WTI", "BRENT", "NATGAS", "GOLD", "SILVER", "ALUM",
"COPPER", "CORN", "SOY", "SUGAR", "WHEAT", "LHOG", "ARACOF", "COCOA", "COT")))
```

Nested For-Loop Code: adjFutData = Data set shown above, window = Rolling window size

```
test = function(adjFutData, window) {

  test = xts(matrix(data = NA,
                    nrow = nrow(adjFutData),
                    ncol = (ncol(adjFutData))),
             order.by = index(adjFutData))

  for (j in 1:ncol(adjFutData)){
    for (i in 1:nrow(adjFutData)){
      if (i>window){
        start = i - window
        end = i-1
        test[i,j] = log(prod(1+adjFutData[start:end,j]))
      }
    }
  }
  return(test)
}
```

Comment: Look into the `rollapply` function from the `zoo` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rollapply(as.zoo(Data), list(-seq(3)), function(x) log(prod(1+x)), fill = NA)
```

This also works:

```
rollapplyr(Data, 4, function(x) log(prod(1+x[1:3])), fill = NA)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `rollapply`, which is in the zoo package:

```
r <- rollapplyr(Data, 3, function(s) log(prod(1+s)), by.column=TRUE)
```

Comment: How can I specify the window size?

Comment: It's the second parameter to `rollapply` and `rollapplyr`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Put up your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Your code produces an equivalent answer to mine but Joshua Ulrich's gives a different answer.